# What does this recursive function do?

Tags: functions, recursion

Let $\sum = \{0, 1\}$. Define $f:\sum^* \rightarrow \sum^*$ (where $\sum^*$ is the set of all words of all lengths including $0$) recursively as follows:

$f(\lambda) = 1$ (where $\lambda$ is the empty word)

$f(0w) = 1w$

$f(1w) = 0f(w)$

So I'm unsure how this function maps a given input to an output. For example, what would be the result of $f(10101)$? Does the function first call itself on $f(1w)$ since the first character of the input is $1$ (where $w$ is now the rest of the word: $0101$)?

Comment: The example you gave is correctly interpreted.  You can start off by noting that f doesnt change the lengths of the words---just switching some bits.  After trying a few examples, you can put into words just what bit-switching is happening.

Comment: Okay, thanks. How do I close this thread as "answered" since yours is just a comment? EDIT: The examples I tried pretty much show that f is just giving the complement of the input and then concatenating a 1 at the end.

Comment: The function changes the first $0$, from the left, into a $1$ (leaving the rest of the word to the left of the $0$ as it is) and all $1$s before that $0$ into $0$s. If there is no first $0$, then it adds a $1$ at the end. In particular, it *does* change the length of some words.

Comment: I think it changes the length of all words, regardless of a $0$ at the beginning. For example, $f(1)$ maps to $01$. And $f(\lambda)$ maps to $1$.

Comment: $f(10)=0f(0)=0f(0\lambda)=01\lambda=01$. Sometimes it changes lengths, sometimes, it doesn't.

Comment: Yikes my observation was wrong!  Gonna edit!  I forgot about the empty word,  which causes the function to increment the length by 1.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Shouldn't it be $f(10) = 0f(0) = 1f(\lambda) = 011$? All recursive calls end with $f(\lambda)$ because that's the base case. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, please disregard my comment, cant edit from my phone.  Sorry for the mislead!  :(

Comment: No. Not all calls end with $f(\lambda)$.  Consider f(00).

Comment: @investigate311 Not all recursive calls end in $f(\lambda)$. This is because case (2) $f(0w)=1w$ is another end. Unless there is a typo there and you really meant $f(0w)=1f(w)$.

Comment: No, it's not a typo but I did incorrectly think that it was $f(0w) = 1f(w)$. I'm not sure why. You're right though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example:

$$f(1\underline{0101})=0f(\underline{0\overline{101}})=01\overline{101}$$

Essentially we replace all leading $1$'s with $0$ and then replace the first $0$ with a $1$. If there are no $0$'s, we append a $1$ onto the end.